# Trouble getting numbers less than 10 to display with two digits on my countdown clock

Tags: javascript

So, in my quest to load a countdown clock on my website, I found some code to display one. More than one example, actually. I selected one that I could understand, and have learned a couple more things along the way. This code works, but does not display numbers less than 10 with two digits (ie. I want 7 seconds to display as 07 seconds).

```
    // set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("May 16, 2014").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);


// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown.innerHTML = days + " DAYS " + hours + ":"
+ minutes + ":" + seconds + " UNTIL DRAWING";


}, 1000);
```

I tried setting the time variables as functions. So instead of above, I had:

```
  seconds = function () {
   parseInt (seconds_left % 60);
   if (seconds_left % 60 < 10) {
   return "0" + seconds_left; }
   else return seconds_left % 60;
}
```

No dice though. Any tips on what else I might try would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding a `'0'` to the beginning of a number if it is less than ten would work:

```
countdown.innerHTML = (days < 10 ? '0' : '') + days + " DAYS " +
                      (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ":" +
                      (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ":" +
                      (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds + " UNTIL DRAWING";
```

Comment: Thanks! So this appears to be a boolean shorthand that I haven't learned yet.

Also, you left out a ) on the hours section, but this worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mrnailbat Ooops, thanks. The syntax `condition ? true : false` is just the shorthand for an inline if statement. It comes in very handy when you don't want to take up 10 lines on an if statement that can be done in one.

Comment: Ahhhhh, very cool. Yes I was very annoyed with some other attempts with if statements that were 5 lines apiece. Thanks again!

Comment: If this answer provided all the information needed ticking the check beside the vote-count allows the wider audience to see that this answer succeeded in meeting all of your criteria, as well as showing appreciation to the contributor.

Comment: And so you know, because there are three parts, the `?` Is called a ternary operator. As opposed to a `+` or a `÷`, which have two parts so they are binary operators.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is just about fine, but you do need to use the "()" after seconds to call a function. Then there's the problem that seconds() is another function.

I renamed the function, moved it up into the interval function, and passed seconds in as a variable.

Here's a way to make it work:

```
//... your other code
hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

var parseSeconds = function (seconds_left) {
   parseInt (seconds_left % 60);
   if (seconds_left % 60 < 10) {
   return "0" + seconds_left; }
   else return seconds_left % 60;
}

// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown.innerHTML = days + " DAYS " + hours + ":"
+ minutes + ":" + parseSeconds(seconds) + " UNTIL DRAWING";

}, 1000);
```

but a better way would be to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you can. They have awesome easy formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) solution. Just replace all your code with this and import moment.js

```
setInterval(function () {
    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
    countdown.innerHTML = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');    
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dxjK/